# Mage specialisation pros and cons

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Out of every corner I hear "Play ice mage" because they seem to be very strong.
Also I often hear that no other spec (arcane, fire) is really worth it because they deal less damage.

Is it true that the other specs make so much less damage?

and in general what are the pros and cons of every spec in detail, the official sites are very neutral on that? (arcane, fire, ice)

Comment: Since the game was released 10 years ago it has changed with every patch. Most players are better served by picking a class and spec they enjoy and learning to play it to the best of their ability. Picking the flavor of the week is usually best left to the top end (hardcore) raiders. If you want to _be_ such a top end hardcore raider, prepare to learn a _lot_ of classes and every spec for them.

Comment: noooooo way, i play for fun! xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranking Dps in World of Warcraft is a hard thing to do but the [following website](http://www.noxxic.com/wow/dps-rankings#630,real,1) is a good reference.

You can simulate the Dps of every class on 1 or 3 targets and depending on your gear level/quality at max level. In my Knowledge there is no equivalent to this when you are not at max level so this will be my base.

The specs rankings are the following for Bis (Best item possible in slot) :
(the rankings are on 26 as there are 26 Dps specs)

- [on 1 target](http://www.noxxic.com/wow/dps-rankings#BiS,real,1) : Frost 9/26, Arcane 16/26 and Fire 25/26
- [on 3 targets](http://www.noxxic.com/wow/dps-rankings#BiS,real,3) : Fire 8/26, Frost 10/26 and Arcane 25/26

You can look at the different item levels, Frost is generally speaking the highest of the three specs and therefore the highest specs in terms of Dps, moreover it has a lot of controls with slows, etc.

Comment: i'm sorry but i dont really understand what the x/y means 
but beside this, thank you for your answer ^^

Comment: On [raidbots.com](http://raidbots.com) you can also see the current "meta"/"ranking" of how the classes perform ingame at the moment or  historically.

Comment: @KyoAkashi: The y represents all of the available damage specs in the entire game, of which there are 26. The x represents the ranking for that particular spec. Click on the links to view the rankings yourself, and they should be more clear.

Comment: @KyoAkashi the X/Y stands for the ranking, there are 26 dps specs, so for example 9/26 is the 9th dps spec on the 26 in total.

Comment: okay thank you very much ^^
i wrote the question from my handy in a short work break so i couldnt look at the sites, sorry

Comment: @Shunwoo: Its probably better to edit the answer to indicate what the X/Y indicates rather than requiring people to read comments

Comment: @Chris Well he said it, he didn't understand the X/Y thing as he didn't see the links yet, and someone else was able to explain it too. So I thought it was ok, But I'll add it.